# Python- Closing bunch of text files opened at the same time with list comprehensions

Tags: python, loops, text, gensim

I am working on an LDA model with gensim. For this, I am basically opening text files, building a dictionary, and then running the model.

To open the files I use this:

```
files = [codecs.open(infile, 'r', 'utf-16', 'ignore') for infile in sample_list]
```

in which sample_list is a list of paths to files. I need to use codecs.open because the texts are in a different language (and I haven't updated Python).

My problem is that I don't know how to close all the files after using them. Any ideas? I've tried a couple of things. I cannot use a regular loop here because of my following step is:

```
texts = [" ".join(file.readlines()[0:]) for file in files]
```

When I use over 5,000 files I get the error '' IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files '' I am thinking that I could open a number of files at a time,  join them, close them, and repeat. Also, keeping the files open is just bad. 
Thank you!

Comment: How do you use the files

Comment: I tokenize the text of each file, then calculate word frequencies and eliminate most common tokens (I have already done other pre-processing, like eliminating stopwords, punctuation, etc.), then build a dictionary and run LDA model with gensim module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def read_contents(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16', 'ignore') as infile:
        return ' '.join(infile)

texts = [read_contents(filename) for filename in sample_list]
```

#### Using `with` is equivalent to doing:

```
def read_contents(filename):
    try:
        infile = codecs.open(filename, 'r', 'utf-16', 'ignore')
        return ' '.join(infile)
    finally:
        infile.close()
```

The `finally` keyword ensures that `close()` gets executed no matter what, even if the script throws an error inside of `try`.

Comment: +1 for the best-practice file handling. I really don't think it's so hard for Python noobs to pick up, and I'm quite annoyed by all the intro material that doesn't do it.

Comment: Thanks! This allows me to open 5,000 files at the same time so it seems to be more efficient than the code I provided. In the function I added filename.close() right below the return line to close the files. What do you think?

Comment: @Connie: That's what the `with` is for. Calling `close` yourself is error-prone, and with `with`, unnecessary. (Also, if you added it *below* the return, it won't even run. Error-prone, see!)

Comment: Great to know! I will start using `with` more often then.

Comment: @Connie it's not opening them at the same time, each file is closed after it's used, so you only have 1 open at a time.  since you don't need to keep more than one open at once, that's the behavior you are aiming for

Comment: Got it. It points to good practices as @Aaron pointed out. And I didn't know `with` was equivalent to `try` and `finally`. Thank you for adding that!